# iPhone XS Max / XR not able to use native resolution when using launch images in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x, xcode10, ios12

I'm using the old school launch image approach instead of a Launch screen storyboard for unrelated reasons.

Normally when Apple has come out with new physical form factors they have added the ability to include images for the new screen sizes in the image asset catalog, which would in turn enable your app to run at **native** resolution instead of being scaled up from previously supported resolutions.

However, this time around that does not seem to be the case. This is how the `LaunchImage` asset looks in the **final** version of Xcode 10 (i.e. **not** GM):

[image]

As you can see there are no drop-ins for iPhone XS Max or iPhone XR, which both have a different (higher) resolution than iPhone X and iPhone XS.

I have seen [other people](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108410) with the same issue, however without any solution.

I can't seem to find any iOS 12 or Xcode 10 documentation suggesting that Apple only supports storyboards or xibs for launch screens going forward.

Comment: I went into Xcode and added a new launch image to my asset file and XS Max and XR are there. If this is an existing app you may need to delete the asset and add a new one and then add all of the images

Comment: @Paulw11 not exactly sure I know what you mean? How would I "detect" the asset?

Comment: @Paulw11 you mean the entire launch screen catalog?

Comment: Yes, or just that one asset if you have other assets in the file

Comment: If you can, though, switch to a launch storyboard and all of this goes away :)

Comment: You're right, removing the old catalog and adding a new one adds the new drop-ins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had it set up like on your picture, and then I noticed that in the inspector on the right there is an 'iOS 8.0 and later' section of checkboxes that weren't checked - when I checked the Portrait one, the XS Max and XR boxes appeared. If you have that checked, maybe unchecking and checking it again would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Thanks to **@Paulw11** for [providing the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402062/iphone-xs-max-xr-not-able-to-use-native-resolution-when-using-launch-images-in/52402316#comment91748101_52402062).*

As of this writing you have to delete your current `LaunchImage` asset (of course remember to copy your files to somewhere else first) and the go into your asset catalog and add a new `LaunchImage` asset. Then it will have the necessary drop-ins:

[image]

This seems like a bug to me, unless they're quietly pushing people to use storyboards?

Comment: I _do_ want to say, however, that this exercise finally did push me over the edge to start using launch storyboards instead :D

Comment: how to come to know what image size need to put in this assets ? Please let me know

Comment: any way to add the `content.json` contents?